# KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([xxxxxx,yyyy,zzzz....]) are in the [index]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**What could I be doing wrong?**

Im new in pandas and I am trying to create a function that will act on data in two columns on my table and create a new column. I get the following error:

Sample Data for js_sales_raw:

```
| Index| No | Category    | item    | sold_inventory | total_unit_cost | profit_set | conversion | percent_rate |
|:---- |:-  |:----------- |:------- |:-------------- |:--------------- |:---------- |----------- |:------------ | 
| 67   | 65 | Accessories | Tops    | 95             | 55              | 1.15       | 0.183836   | 0.396592     |
| 61   | 59 | Accessories | Bottoms | 101            | 93              | 1.35       | 0.177796   | 0.525369     |
```

```
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([ 20.649334341811475,   8.654894443721654,   71.69318364321492,\n                61.62061099080671,  -46.11961777489416,   20.57743384815745,\n              -112.15877185149225, -181.85544403849417,  3.1769390173655188,\n               -84.96483841029566,\n              ...\n                              nan,                 nan,                 nan,\n                              nan,                 nan,                 nan,\n                              nan,                 nan,                 nan,\n                              nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=245)] are in the [index]"
```

Here is my code:

```
def price_calc(x):
    if x <= 0.05:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'])]
    elif x <= 0.10:
        return js_sales_raw.loc['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - js_sales_raw['conversion'])
    elif x <= 0.15:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*2))]
    elif x <= 0.20:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*3))]
    elif x <= 0.30:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*4))]
    elif x <= 0.40:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*5))]
    elif x <= 0.50:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*6))]
    elif x <= 0.70:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*7))]
    elif x <= 0.80:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*8))]
    elif x <= 0.90:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*9))]
    elif x <= 0.95:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*10))]
    elif x <= 1.00:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*11))]
    elif x <= 1.20:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*12))]
    elif x <= 1.40:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*13))]
    else:
        return js_sales_raw.loc[js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'] - (js_sales_raw['conversion']*14))]

js_sales_raw['latest_price'] = js_sales_raw['percent_rate'].apply(price_calc)
```

Comment: Why do you need all those loc calls?

Comment: please add sample data you are using

Comment: @Chandan. Thanks. Added some sample data

Comment: @cs95. Tbh, I'm not so sure its the correct way to do it. I want to use data in two columns within  a function depending on the data in a separate column. I googled some solutions and this is the best I could come up with. If you can suggest to me a better way, I would be so grateful.

Comment: @Chandan excuse me but I'm not passing anything of the sort.

Comment: @cs95 sorry i was messaging to evacoder

Comment: @evacoder Inside your `price_calc` function conditions you are calling `loc` on js_sales_raw df js_sales_raw.loc`[`js_sales_raw['total_unit_cost'] * (js_sales_raw['profit_set'])`]` total unit cost is `integer` profit_set is `float` after multiplication result will be floating which will then be passed to `loc` method.

Comment: @evacoder `loc` method only takes `integer` or `string` for index you are passing floating point result of calculation